# ansible automatic apt upgrade and all find modified configuration file

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, apt, ansible

With ansible do an automatic apt upgrade from all our servers. That is no problem, but as a result we want to see **only** the "configuration file" which has kept, so we could check them afterwards.

In the following task

```
debug
  msg
```

we see everything, but I only want fetch something like:

```
[servername1]
    Configuration file '/etc/apache2/apache2.conf'
     ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
     ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
     ==> Keeping old config file as default.
```

And this for all servers and all kept configuration files.

I did not find a solution yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.